Is khalid ibn yazid ibn abi malik reliable?
As-salamu alaykum wa Rahmatullahi wa barakatoh.
I have a issue with Ahadith regarding the narrator khalid ibn yazid ibn abi malik concerning whether he is reliable or not. I saw some ahadith with him being in the chain narration and the hadith was weak. I couldn't find anything about him. The hadith is sunan ibn majah 4337.
JazakAllahu Khayran 

Please share the hadith in question with at least a link to the Arabic original... Because the enumeration of hadith books is edition based it's not something the authors invented, but later scholars/editors who may have re-arranged the book for some purposes.

Ahadith on reported via him by ibn Majah
I suppose that you are referring to the following hadith:

It was narrated from Abu Umamah that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
“There is no one whom Allah will admit to Paradise but Allah will marry him to seventy-two wives, two from houris and seventy from his inheritance from the people of Hell, all of whom will have desirable front passages and he will have a male member that never becomes flaccid (i.e., soft and limp).’”

That was reported via the following narrator chain in Sunan ibn Majah:

حَدَّثَنَا هِشَامُ بْنُ خَالِدٍ الأَزْرَقُ أَبُو مَرْوَانَ الدِّمَشْقِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا خَالِدُ بْنُ يَزِيدَ بْنِ أَبِي مَالِكٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ خَالِدِ بْنِ مَعْدَانَ، عَنْ أَبِي أُمَامَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ
we were informed by Hisham ibn Khalid al-Azraq abu Marwan a-Dimashqi from Khalid ibn Yazid ibn abi Malik from his father from Khalid ibn Ma'adaan from abu Umamah from the Messenger of Allah, Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him.

Ibn Majah reported other ahadith via Khalid ibn Yazid ibn Malik as you may find in the chapter of charity and the book of purification and its sunnah. In all these reports the narrator reported via his father. Further ibn Majah himself reported all these three narrations via his teacher Hisham ibn Khalid al-Azraq also known as Hisham ibn Khalid as-Salaami (or al-QUrashi or a-Dimashqi) only the report in the chapter on charity with one intermediate his teacher 'Ubayd Allah ibn 'Abd al-Kareem both of these teachers were of a high level of trust. Nevertheless, all three narrations on Sunnah.com were qualified as weak.
On his jarh and ta'adeel
In the following, I'll quote some statements from scholars on the qualification of Khalid ibn Yazid ibn abi Malik as a narrator.
In his book a-Do'afaa' wal Matrukoon الضعفاء والمتروكون a-Daraqotni mentioned him in one sentence:

١٩٧ - خالد بن يزيد بن أبي مالك، شامي، عن أبيه، وأبوه من الثقات. (Source)
Khalid ibn Yazid ibn abi Malik a-Shaami, (reported) from his father, and his father is counted among the trustworthy narrators.

Ibn abi Hatim mentioned him in his al-Jarh wa a-Ta'adeel الجرح والتعديل:

١٦٢٣ - خالد بن يزيد بن أبي مالك وهو ابن يزيد بن عبد الرحمن بن أبي مالك الشامي واسم أبي مالك هانئ الهمداني روى عن أبيه عن جده روى عنه ابن المبارك والوليد بن مسلم والهيثم بن خارجة وسليمان ابن عبد الرحمن سمعت أبي يقول ذلك.
Khalid bin Yazid ibn Abi Malik, who is the son of Yazid bin Abdurrahman ibn Abi Malik a-Shami, and the name of abu Malik is Hani al-Hamadani. He narrated on the authority of his father from his grandfather. Ibn Al-Mubarak, Al-Walid ibn Muslim, al-Haitham ibn Kharijah, and Sulayman ibn Abdurrahman narrated on his authority. I heard my father say that.
قال أبو محمد روى عنه محمد ابن شعيب بن شابور.
Abu Muhammad further sid Muhammad ibn SHo'aib ibn Shaaboor narrated on his authority.
حدثنا عبد الرحمن قال سئل أبو زرعة عنه فقال: لا بأس به حدث عنه ابن المبارك.
Abduffahman told us that abu Zura’ah was asked about him and he said: There is nothing wrong with him. Ibn al-Mubarak narrated on his authority.
حدثنا عبد الرحمن قال سئل أبي عن خالد بن يزيد بن أبي مالك فقال: يروي أحاديث مناكير.
Abdurrahman told us that my father was asked about Khalid ibn Yazid bin Abi Malik and he said: He narrates strange hadiths (manaakeer).

Ibn A'dy in his book al-Kamil fi a-Do'afaa' الكامل في ضعفاء الرجال (See here and in the following pages) confirmed that Ahmad ibn Hanbal, an-Nasaa-i (see 170 in his book here) and Yahya ibn Ma'yn regarded him as dai'f (see here in the book of al-'Aqili) or in best case as not trustworthy.
Ibn Shaaheen actually in his book on narrators on whom there's a difference of opinion concerning their qualifications as a narrator ذكر من اختلف العلماء ونقاد الحديث فيه (see here and the following page) mentioned that: Ahmad ibn Salih regarded him as trustworthy, and he also added a report of Ahmad ibn Hanbal qualifying a Khalid ibn Yazid as trustworthy, where in the narrator stated I'm unsure whether he was meaning Khalid ibn Yazid ibn abi Malik or Khalid ibn Yazid ibn Sabeeh. And he confirmed the opinion of Yahya ibn Ma'yn by two different reports regarding him as less reliable. Nevertheless, he concluded by suggesting that if both Ahmads consider a person trustworthy, then none can say he's weak.
Ibn Hibban mentioned him in his al-Majrooheen كتاب المجروحين (see here and the following page) presenting him as a faqih and a sadooq narrator, who made a lot of mistakes in his narration and had some manaakeer and he wouldn't accept his reports from his father if they had no other backup.
Ibn 'Asakir mentioned with a narrator chain -that I have shortened here- in his Tareekh Dimashq a heavy statement of Yahya ibn Ma'yn about this narrator:

سمعت أحمد بن أبي الحواري يقول سمعت يحيى بن معين يقول بالعراق كتاب ينبغي أن يدفن وبالشام كتاب ينبغي أن يدفن فأما الذي بالعراق فكتاب التفسير عن الكلبي عن أبي صالح عن ابن عباس وأما الذي بالشام فكتاب الديات لخالد بن يزيد بن أبي مالك لم يرض أن يكذب على أبيه حتى كذب على أصحاب رسول الله (صلى الله عليه وسلم)
I heard Ahmad ibn abi al-Hawari say: I heard Yahya ibn Ma’in say: In 'Iraq, there is a book that should be buried, and in a-Shaam there is a book that should be buried. As for the one in 'Iraq, it is the Book of Tafsir, on the authority of al-Kalbi, on the authority of Abu Salih, on the authority of Ibn Abbas. As for the one in a-Shaam, it is the Book of Blood Money (Diiyyaat) by Khalid ibn Yazid ibn Abi Malik. He was not satisfied to lie about his father, so he lied about the companions of the Messenger of Allah (may Allah bless him and grant him peace).
قال أحمد بن أبي الحواري وكنت قد سمعت من خالد بن يزيد بن أبي مالك كتاب الديات فأعطيته لابن عبدوس العطار فقطعه وأعطى الناس فيه حوائج (Source)
Ahmad ibn Abi al-Hawari said: I had heard from Khalid ibn Yazid ibn Abi Malik the Book of Blood Money, so I gave it to ibn 'Abdus al-'Attar, so he tore it up and gave people what they needed in it.

You may find further qualifications and mention of him in Tareekh al-Bukhari in a-Do'afaa' wal Matrookoon of ibn al-Jawzi and al-Mizzi's Tahdeeb al-Kamal etc. and also in this hadith database where his general qualification was "matrook".
